# How to specify java version when I use mvn package command without change environment path

Tags: java, maven

My environment java version is jdk8,Now I want use Maven command `mvn package`  to compile some project.How to specify java version(like java11) to compile it whitout change environment path,because java version is a dynamic arguments in my process

Comment: You can't. You need to use java 11 or higher to compile sources for java 11.

Comment: try this command `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/  mvn clean package` repalce path with jdk you need

Comment: I think set temporary path is good way @stanley

Answer (score 2):

Use this command:`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/ mvn clean package`

Replace the path with JDK that you need.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling Sources Using [A Different JDK](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html)

```
    <project>
      [...]
      <build>
        [...]
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <verbose>true</verbose>
              <fork>true</fork>
              <executable><!-- path-to-javac --></executable>
              <compilerVersion>11</compilerVersion>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
        [...]
      </build>
      [...]
    </project>
```

Well the side effect is we have to edit the pom.xml file.

- We may keep different version of pom.xml file, like `pom-java11.xml`, `pom-java17.xml`
- `mvn -f <other pom file>` for your task, like `mvn -f pom-java11.xml ...`

Answer (score -1):

In pom.xml you can define the version of JDK

**Like**

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```